# stop current activity and pass other activity

Tags: android

I want to stop or kill current activity and pass another activity.I tried below code but it doesn't stop current activity

```
    if (newMessage.equals("0")) {

            Intent send_push = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Login.class);
            // send_push.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            // send_push.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(send_push);
        }
```

Comment: Try calling `finish()` right after you call `startActivity(send_push)`

Comment: I tried this,but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
 send_push = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Login.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(send_push);
```

The flags need to be used togther.